# Android: ImageView next to TextView not showing

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I have a `TextView` and `ImageView` in a `ListView` row, positioned next to each other. However, the `ImageView` doesn't show up at all, and doesn't register clicks either. This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem seems to lie in the `layout_toRightOf` line, if I remove it, the `ImageView` is shown, but in the wrong place. But I don't understand why it's causing a problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Try using Linear Layout with horizontal  orientation

Comment: @Technicolor seems  `android:layout_width="320dp"` is too much for your screen why you exactly need 320 dp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `TextView` is pushing the `ImageView` off the screen.

You can fix this using a `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight`

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

More info on the `layout_weight` attribute:

This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. Default weight is zero.

For example, if there are three text fields and two of them declare a weight of 1, while the other is given no weight, the third text field without weight will not grow and will only occupy the area required by its content. The other two will expand equally to fill the space remaining after all three fields are measured. If the third field is then given a weight of 2 (instead of 0), then it is now declared more important than both the others, so it gets half the total remaining space, while the first two share the rest equally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LinearLayout with weight.. if you set fixed width and the size of the phone is small, it will either stretch out of the screen.

//do linearlayout with orientation horizontal

```
<LinearLayout 
   ...
   orientation = "horizontal"
   ...
>

    <TextView
        ....
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ...
    />

    <Button
       ....
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       ...
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Play with `android:layout_weight`, you will understand